# Doctrine PreUpdate never worked

Tags: php, events, symfony, doctrine-orm, lifecycle

I have searched, and there is a lot of questions wiith the same problem, but none of them solves to my issue.

I have an Entity, here is it's code:

```
/*
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class MyEntity
{
    // some preoperties here...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="500")
     */
    private $delivery = null;

    /**
     * @var $deliveryOn bool
     *
     * Virtual field used for $delivery property organization
     */
    private $deliveryOn = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preSetDelivery()
    {
        if ($this->deliveryOn == false)
            $this->delivery = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad()
     */
    public function loadDeliveryOn()
    {
        if ($this->delivery != null)
            $this->deliveryOn = true;
    }
}
```

`loadDeliveryOn` method perfectly works all the time. But the `preSetDelivery` fired **only** when I persist the entity to the database for the first time. I want it to be called when object is updated too, but it doesn't work. And I have no any idea why.

My edit controller:

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    // some code here...
    // ...

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $em->flush();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: "I want it to be called when object is updated too" are you talking about the php object or the row in the database being updated ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the PrePersist? Does the update work if it's on it's own.

Comment: @Mark nothing changes

Comment: @mpm I'm talking about updating an object, not a database row.

Comment: My understanding is that @PreUpdate is only called before a database row is updated, because it's called inside the flush() method (according to the doctrine doc).

Answer (score 0):

From official [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#preupdate) concerning `preUpdate`:

> Changes to fields of the passed entities are not recognized by the
>   flush operation anymore, use the computed change-set passed to the
>   event to modify primitive field values.

If you have access to `UnitOfWork` maybe there is a way to recompute change-set as there is in [onFlush](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#onflush)?

Comment: Okay. All I want to do is to change one entity of field depends on another field. And since I have a lot of forms that uses this entity, I want an entity-based solution. SO what Should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

if you use inheritance - for example @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
you need to add @ORM\MappedSuperclass in the parent class

Answer (score -1):

PreUpdate only fires if there are actual changes on the entity. If you don't change anything in the form, there will be no changes on the entity, and no preUpdate listeners will be called.